# How to increment a solidity variable using a function

Tags: solidity

i want to count every time that i call the function , i tried to increase the number by every time that I called but it doesn't work , it always gives  1 .

```
function getdeployedcontracts () public returns (string, uint,uint,uint,uint,uint,address,address) {



     Request storage request= contracts [index];

    return (request.d,
            request.valuev,
            request.r,
            request.t,
            request.n,
            request.r,
            request.recipient);
     index+= 1;

 }
```

Comment: @smarx ,@ MSwezey  after deleting view , i cant see the return variable anymore

Comment: this code is actually valid, as `index` is a variable instantiated inside of the function and thus does not modify state.

Comment: The logic behind the code may need to be redone.

Answer (score 3):

`view` functions are called via a "call" rather than a transaction and thus cannot change state.

Remove the `view` modifier, and things should work.

Comment: ,@ MSwezey after deleting view , i cant see the return variable anymore

Comment: Transactions don't have return values. If you want to communicate a value back to an external caller, you'll need to emit an event.

Answer (score 2):

`view` marks the function as read-only, aka, cannot write state changes.

Remove `view`, and it should work as expected.

Update - your code does not save state still, below properly increments and save state

```
    uint index;

    function getdeployedcontracts () public returns (uint result) {
            result = index; // get & return previous value, staring with 0
            index += 1; // increment value
     }
```

Update #2:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract U256 {

    struct Request{
        string name;
        uint a;
        uint b;
        uint c;
        uint d;
        uint e;
        address a1;
        address a2;
    }

    Request[] contracts;
    uint index;

    constructor() public {
        contracts.push(Request('first',1,2,3,4,5,address(0),address(0)));
        contracts.push(Request('second',2,3,4,5,6,address(0),address(0)));
    }

    function getdeployedcontracts () public returns (string memory, uint,uint,uint,uint,uint,address,address) {

        Request memory request = contracts[index];

        index += 1;

        return (request.name,
                request.a,
                request.b,
                request.c,
                request.d,
                request.e,
                request.a1,
                request.a2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @smarx ,@ MSwezey after deleting view , i cant see the return variable anymore

Comment: I verified on remix, the return value is there still. 

But your code needs to be updated. See my updated comment in 1 minute.

Comment: could i ask which compiler version that u use , i tried with 4.17 and it is still the same

Comment: Compiler version doesn't matter in this particular instance. You need to check your transactions decoded output. What tool(s) are you using? Remix?

Comment: yes remix , u can see the code that i tried . actually i want to view one request in my array like contract [index]  , so i want used the idea of counter to show at first , 0 then 1 ,.... . but i cant know how to express my idea , (i edited the code )

Comment: you will not see a return value in the righthand side. 
You have to open up the details of the transaction in the console window as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/GiICUBY

Comment: I don't understand this part "actually i want to view one request in my array like contract [index] , " I edited my example to show how to return 0 first, then increment

Comment: could u see my code now? in my array (contracts) i have different requests and i want to show the first request at beginning and in the second call i will show the second so i used the (index+1) .

Comment: I see. see my updated comment. I believe is what your looking for. 
Yours didn't work as it was hitting `return` so the index value never was being incremented

Answer (score 0):

put `index+= 1` or `index.increment()` or `index = index+1` before `return`.

The function stop when something return.